# Facebook send invitation not working

Tags: ios, facebook

I just tried this code to send invitation to Facebook friends through my application. This is the code and I got a `log` msg sent to the user ID I've given on top and Facebook invitation screen pop up.

I got the correct person who has the user ID I've given and I sent the invitation, but in that profile didn't see any notification. Is this the correct code or need any changes?

Please help me and thanks in advance.

```
NSString *facebookID = @"100000797858986";
NSMutableDictionary* params =
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:facebookID forKey:@"to"];

NSString *message = @"SOME_MESSAGE";
NSString *title = @"TITLE";

[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
    message:message
    title:title
    parameters:params handler:^(FBWebDialogResult   result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) 
    {
            if (error)
            {
                    // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
                    NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
            }
            else
            {
                    if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted)
                    {
                            // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                            NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            NSLog(@"Request Sent. %@", params);
                    }
            }
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Look my code here and follow FB app developer page setting for your ref: http://pastebin.com/1d4Jc4X0

Make sure your facebook app id is same in both developer page and info in xcode. Next, enable sandbox mode and must fill canvas url [under app on facebook category] in developer page.
[image]

1. Make **yes** for this, Do you want to make this app and all its live
   features available to the general public?
2. One more thing, You need to enter your contact email address under
   settings section.
3. Make sure you have Registered your iphone App as "**App on Facebook**"
   Type Select how your app integrates with Facebook under Basic App
   Settings.

[image]

Add a field as mentioned below, `FacebookAppId` in that add your facebook app id, which is generated in facebook developer page, and make sure the bundle id same in both **xcode** and **facebook developer page.**

[image]

Comment: how to enable sandobx mode when go to review status there is a question but i cant enabled the yes button that is inactive can you just give information how to do that the app id i configured is correct

Comment: Hi, i checked sent message sucessfully but still didnt get in facebook notification in account. I checked in simulator is any issue or only work in real device ?

Comment: You made some mistake, and, It'll work in both simulator and real device.

Comment: i try to add my code here but couldnt so just see i created code as a new question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235506/this-is-code-for-fb-invtation-not-working

Comment: Just try this as per my code. added one link , click and see code

Comment: sorry i didnt get you can you explain what you mean

Comment: Open this link, and see my code,  http://pastebin.com/1d4Jc4X0 ,i think your fb devloper page setting for app is incomplete,

Comment: what need to configure in that

Comment: http://support.qualityunit.com/172666-How-to-setup-Facebook-application, follow this link till website and contact details.

Comment: I looked your url http://pastebin.com/1d4Jc4X0 in this self.loggedInUser getting error not defined where need to declare this. Also where need to pass the facebook app id in this code or to id for friend.

Comment: add this in .h file @property (strong, nonatomic) id<FBGraphUser> loggedInUser; and add this in .m file


- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
    self.loggedInUser = user;
}

Comment: I checked with your code still i got success message but not seen invitation in facebook

Comment: if you did these steps properly, sure u'll get result. somewhere you did mistake. ok, give your id i'll send sample project

Comment: creotech.shinu@gmail.com

Comment: hi i didnt get mail can you send the sample project

Answer (score 0):

You should check invitation in safari/facebook app with your correct person facebook account ic (facebook app id person account ) in iphone/ipad.

Comment: I checked it but didnt get invitation in facebook